# WiX Installer wrong about newer version already installed

Tags: wix, windows-installer, sccm

I have used WiX Install tools in Visual Studio to create create an installer for my C# Windows Forms application.

The Installer works when invoked independently (command line or double-click); it uninstalls the existing version (1.0.1.2) and installs the new version (1.0.2.1) but the objective is to have SCCM push the application out to our 50+ workstations.

> Answers to questions that have been asked:
>
> It is configured in SCCM as an *Application*. This is only my third
>   experience with SCCM, I am not familiar with Packages.
>
> The Detection Method is 2 Rules:
>   Product Code {81748469-6B08-4C6C-99B5-BFCE7202FE06} must exist.
>   File *%ProgramFiles%\PHSRP\PHSRP_Dashboard.exe* with Modified Date >=
>   *7/2/2019 12:00:00 AM* must be present.

The installation is failing when SCCM is pushing it out. The installation log indicates that the installer believes that a newer version already exists, but this is not true.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="81748469-6b08-4c6c-99b5-bfce7202fe06" Name="PHSRP Dashboard" Language="1033" Version="1.0.2.1" Manufacturer="CSUS Public Health Survey Research Program" UpgradeCode="8420CB2B-6692-4BB9-A15A-023C7E69FB26">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Platform="x64"/>

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed."
                  AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes"
                  IgnoreRemoveFailure="yes"
     />
    <MediaTemplate />
    <!-- UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal"     Adds License dialog         -->
    <!-- UIRef Id="WixUI_Advanced"    Adds multiple dialog option popups  -->


    <Feature Id="MainProduct" Title="PHSRP Dashboard" Level="1" Absent="disallow">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_StartMenu_Dashboard"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_DashboardAutoStart"/>
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
        <Directory Id="PHSRP" Name="PHSRP" />
      </Directory>

      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
        <Directory Id="PHSRP_Menu" Name="PHSRP"/>
      </Directory>

      <Directory Id="StartupFolder"/>

    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="PHSRP">

      <Component Id="CMP_Dashboard.EXE" Guid="939EC7DE-E6BD-4364-BFC7-7B03C03B7CBB">
        <File Id="FILE_Dashboard.EXE" Source="$(var.PHSRP_Dashboard.TargetDir)PHSRP_Dashboard.exe" KeyPath ="yes"/>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="CMP_DasboardConfig" Guid="4081EC5F-EAD0-4003-8B43-DFF1EF6B4348">
        <File Id="FILE_DashboardConfig" Source="$(var.PHSRP_Dashboard.TargetDir)\PHSRP_Dashboard.exe.config" KeyPath ="yes"/>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="CMP_EntityFramework" Guid="D685B056-E64C-4C9A-B0B0-C74DC5EF085E">
        <File Id="FILE_EntityFramework" Source="$(var.PHSRP_Dashboard.TargetDir)\EntityFramework.dll" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="CMP_EntityFrameworkSqlServer" Guid="E017DCC8-1439-4CB6-BFDB-A8C86BF99D74">
        <File Id="FILE_EntityFrameworkSqlServer" Source="$(var.PHSRP_Dashboard.TargetDir)\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="CMP_ReportViewerCommon" Guid="972220E8-5DD4-451D-847D-32DAC050D639">
        <File Id="FILE_ReportViewerCommon" Source="C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="CMP_ReportViewerDataVisualization" Guid="B0AF7500-5743-4B48-85FA-9BA12E3B554A">
        <File Id="FILE_ReportViewerDataVisualization" Source="C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="CMP_ReportViewerProcessingObjectModel" Guid="75E5E7AD-E1AF-41BC-BC95-464272966629">
        <File Id="FILE_ReportViewerProcessingObjectModel" Source="C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="CMP_ReportViewerWinForms" Guid="831D08B1-047B-46E0-AA89-C1D47B0B4EBE">
        <File Id="FILE_ReportViewerWinForms" Source="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\ReportViewer\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="CMP_SQLServerTypes" Guid="EE385FEE-A4C9-4F9A-800E-F2B9C573DCA7">
        <File Id="FILE_SQLServerTypes" Source="C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="CMP_SystemNetHttp" Guid="F56581DD-D9D0-4140-BB66-9DEF7FF66D7B">
        <File Id="FILE_SystemNetHttp" Source="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Net.Http.dll" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>

    <DirectoryRef Id="PHSRP_Menu">
      <Component Id="CMP_StartMenu_Dashboard" Guid="B8C6D5CE-26BD-45E1-904D-97FC3EEADAE8">
        <Shortcut Id="SCUT_RunDashboard" Name="PHSRP Dashboard" Description="Start Dashboard" 
                  Target="[#FILE_Dashboard.EXE]"
                  WorkingDirectory="PHSRP" />

        <RemoveFolder Id="UI_RemoveShortcut" Directory="PHSRP_Menu" On="uninstall"/>
        <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\PHSRP\PHSRP_Dashboard">
          <RegistryValue Name="sm_shortcut" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
        </RegistryKey>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>

    <DirectoryRef Id="StartupFolder">
      <Component Id="CMP_DashboardAutoStart" Guid="E10E004B-8A38-43F9-8365-4C44267565F2">
        <Shortcut Id="SCUT_DashboardAutoStart" Name="PHSRP Dashboard" Description="AutoStart Dashboard"
                  Target="[#FILE_Dashboard.EXE]"
                  WorkingDirectory="PHSRP" />

        <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\PHSRP\PHSRP_Dashboard">
          <RegistryValue Name="su_shortcut" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
        </RegistryKey>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>

  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

The existing version of the software is 1.0.1.1

[Existing application file properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YcsQ.png)

The installation command used by SCCM

```
msiexec /i "WixInstaller.msi" /qn /norestart /L*V "C:\sys\logs\db_install.log"
```

The installation log file:

```
    === Verbose logging started: 7/11/2019  9:29:29  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00  Calling process: C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (48:5C) [09:29:29:302]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (48:5C) [09:29:29:302]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (48:5C) [09:29:29:302]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: WixInstaller.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (48:5C) [09:29:29:302]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (48:5C) [09:29:29:302]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (48:5C) [09:29:29:317]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (48:5C) [09:29:29:317]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (48:5C) [09:29:29:317]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (20:B8) [09:29:29:317]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\5q\WixInstaller.msi
MSI (s) (20:B8) [09:29:29:317]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\5q\WixInstaller.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: User policy value 'DisableMedia' is 0
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownMedia' is 0
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: SOURCEMGMT: Media enabled only if package is safe.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: SOURCEMGMT: Looking for sourcelist for product {81748469-6B08-4C6C-99B5-BFCE7202FE06}
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: SOURCEMGMT: Adding {81748469-6B08-4C6C-99B5-BFCE7202FE06}; to potential sourcelist list (pcode;disk;relpath).
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: SOURCEMGMT: Now checking product {81748469-6B08-4C6C-99B5-BFCE7202FE06}
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: SOURCEMGMT: Media is enabled for product.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: SOURCEMGMT: Attempting to use LastUsedSource from source list.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: SOURCEMGMT: Processing net source list.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: SOURCEMGMT: Trying source C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\5q\.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer 3: 2 
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: Specifed source is already in a list.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: Machine policy value 'DisableBrowse' is 0
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownBrowse' is 0
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: Adding new sources is allowed.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: Set LastUsedSource to: C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\5q\.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: Set LastUsedType to: n.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: Set LastUsedIndex to: 1.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: SOURCEMGMT: Resolved source to: 'C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\5q\'
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: SRSetRestorePoint skipped for this transaction.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:317]: File will have security applied from OpCode.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\5q\WixInstaller.msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DigitalSignature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\5q\WixInstaller.msi is not digitally signed
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\5q\WixInstaller.msi is permitted to run because the user token authorizes execution (system or service token).
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Original package ==> C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\5q\WixInstaller.msi
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Package we're running from ==> C:\WINDOWS\Installer\30cf3.msi
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{81748469-6B08-4C6C-99B5-BFCE7202FE06}'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{81748469-6B08-4C6C-99B5-BFCE7202FE06}'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Transforms are not secure.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Control 
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiLogFileLocation property. Its value is 'C:\sys\logs\db_install.log'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Command Line: REBOOT=ReallySuppress CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\5q CLIENTUILEVEL=3 CLIENTPROCESSID=6472 
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackageCode property. Its value is '{B44E8FB7-8E4E-48D4-8D07-CB34010243AB}'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Product Code passed to Engine.Initialize:           '{81748469-6B08-4C6C-99B5-BFCE7202FE06}'
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Product Code from property table before transforms: '{81748469-6B08-4C6C-99B5-BFCE7202FE06}'
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Product Code from property table after transforms:  '{81748469-6B08-4C6C-99B5-BFCE7202FE06}'
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Determined that existing product (either this product or the product being upgraded with a patch) is installed per-machine.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Product {81748469-6B08-4C6C-99B5-BFCE7202FE06} is admin assigned: LocalSystem owns the publish key.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Product {81748469-6B08-4C6C-99B5-BFCE7202FE06} is managed.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: MSI_LUA: Credential prompt not required, user is an admin
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ProductState property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Specifed source is already in a list.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Adding new sources is allowed.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Package name retrieved from configuration data: 'WixInstaller.msi'
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 0
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Product {81748469-6B08-4C6C-99B5-BFCE7202FE06} is admin assigned: LocalSystem owns the publish key.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Product {81748469-6B08-4C6C-99B5-BFCE7202FE06} is managed.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Running product '{81748469-6B08-4C6C-99B5-BFCE7202FE06}' with elevated privileges: Product is assigned.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding REBOOT property. Its value is 'ReallySuppress'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CURRENTDIRECTORY property. Its value is 'C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\5q'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTUILEVEL property. Its value is '3'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTPROCESSID property. Its value is '6472'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Machine policy value 'DisableAutomaticApplicationShutdown' is 0
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRestartManagerSessionKey property. Its value is '32643088af72814b9d60a08f9f058ba9'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: RESTART MANAGER: Session opened.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: TRANSFORMS property is now: 
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PRODUCTLANGUAGE property. Its value is '1033'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionDatabase property. Its value is '200'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Favorites
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Documents
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Pictures
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Public\Desktop
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\Fonts
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Note: 1: 2898 2: MS Sans Serif 3: MS Sans Serif 4: 0 5: 16 
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: MSI_LUA: Setting MsiRunningElevated property to 1 because the install is already running elevated.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRunningElevated property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding USERNAME property. Its value is 'CSUS User'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding COMPANYNAME property. Its value is 'CSU Sacramento'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASE property. Its value is 'C:\WINDOWS\Installer\30cf3.msi'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OriginalDatabase property. Its value is 'C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\5q\WixInstaller.msi'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Machine policy value 'MsiDisableEmbeddedUI' is 0
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: EEUI - Disabling MsiEmbeddedUI for service because it's not a quiet/basic install
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PatchPackage 
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UILevel property. Its value is '2'.
=== Logging started: 7/11/2019  9:29:29 ===
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: APPCOMPAT: [DetectVersionLaunchCondition] Launch condition already passes.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Doing action: INSTALL
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 9:29:29: INSTALL.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Running ExecuteSequence
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:333]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 9:29:29: FindRelatedProducts.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:348]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED property. Its value is '{61C1C89E-DC8D-42BC-953C-913E8CE3DD08}'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:348]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MIGRATE property. Its value is '{61C1C89E-DC8D-42BC-953C-913E8CE3DD08}'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:348]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED property. Its value is '{8BC4D6BF-C0CF-48EB-A229-FC692208DFF0}'.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:348]: Doing action: LaunchConditions
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:348]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 9:29:29: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 9:29:29: LaunchConditions.
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:348]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:348]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:348]: Product: PHSRP Dashboard -- A newer version of PHSRP Dashboard is already installed.

A newer version of PHSRP Dashboard is already installed.
Action ended 9:29:29: LaunchConditions. Return value 3.
Action ended 9:29:29: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Property(S): UpgradeCode = {8420CB2B-6692-4BB9-A15A-023C7E69FB26}
Property(S): StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(S): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(S): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(S): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(S): Manufacturer = CSUS Public Health Survey Research Program
Property(S): ProductCode = {81748469-6B08-4C6C-99B5-BFCE7202FE06}
Property(S): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(S): ProductName = PHSRP Dashboard
Property(S): ProductVersion = 1.0.2.1
Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED;WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED
Property(S): WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED = {61C1C89E-DC8D-42BC-953C-913E8CE3DD08}
Property(S): WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED = {8BC4D6BF-C0CF-48EB-A229-FC692208DFF0}
Property(S): MsiLogFileLocation = C:\sys\logs\db_install.log
Property(S): PackageCode = {B44E8FB7-8E4E-48D4-8D07-CB34010243AB}
Property(S): ProductState = 1
Property(S): REBOOT = ReallySuppress
Property(S): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\5q
Property(S): CLIENTUILEVEL = 3
Property(S): CLIENTPROCESSID = 6472
Property(S): MsiRestartManagerSessionKey = 32643088af72814b9d60a08f9f058ba9
Property(S): PRODUCTLANGUAGE = 1033
Property(S): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(S): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(S): VersionNT = 603
Property(S): VersionNT64 = 603
Property(S): WindowsBuild = 9600
Property(S): ServicePackLevel = 0
Property(S): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(S): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(S): WindowsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\
Property(S): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(S): System64Folder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\
Property(S): SystemFolder = C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\
Property(S): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(S): TempFolder = C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\
Property(S): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(S): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(S): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(S): AppDataFolder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\
Property(S): FavoritesFolder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Favorites\
Property(S): NetHoodFolder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(S): PersonalFolder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Documents\
Property(S): PrintHoodFolder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(S): RecentFolder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(S): SendToFolder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(S): TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(S): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(S): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\
Property(S): MyPicturesFolder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Pictures\
Property(S): AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(S): StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(S): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
Property(S): FontsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\
Property(S): GPTSupport = 1
Property(S): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(S): Msix64 = 6
Property(S): Intel = 6
Property(S): PhysicalMemory = 8076
Property(S): VirtualMemory = 7770
Property(S): AdminUser = 1
Property(S): MsiTrueAdminUser = 1
Property(S): LogonUser = SYSTEM
Property(S): UserSID = S-1-5-18
Property(S): UserLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ComputerName = AA-PH-6L4HKH2
Property(S): SystemLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ScreenX = 1024
Property(S): ScreenY = 768
Property(S): CaptionHeight = 19
Property(S): BorderTop = 1
Property(S): BorderSide = 1
Property(S): TextHeight = 16
Property(S): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(S): ColorBits = 32
Property(S): TTCSupport = 1
Property(S): Time = 9:29:29
Property(S): Date = 7/11/2019
Property(S): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.7.3190.0
Property(S): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.3.17763.1
Property(S): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(S): MsiRunningElevated = 1
Property(S): Privileged = 1
Property(S): USERNAME = CSUS User
Property(S): COMPANYNAME = CSU Sacramento
Property(S): DATABASE = C:\WINDOWS\Installer\30cf3.msi
Property(S): OriginalDatabase = C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\5q\WixInstaller.msi
Property(S): UILevel = 2
Property(S): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): MIGRATE = {61C1C89E-DC8D-42BC-953C-913E8CE3DD08}
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:348]: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
MSI (s) (20:6C) [09:29:29:348]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (20:B8) [09:29:29:348]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
MSI (s) (20:B8) [09:29:29:348]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
=== Logging stopped: 7/11/2019  9:29:29 ===
MSI (s) (20:B8) [09:29:29:348]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (20:B8) [09:29:29:348]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (20:B8) [09:29:29:348]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (20:B8) [09:29:29:348]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (20:B8) [09:29:29:348]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (20:B8) [09:29:29:348]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (48:5C) [09:29:29:364]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (48:5C) [09:29:29:364]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 7/11/2019  9:29:29 ===
```

So, why does SCCM/WiX think that 1 is greater than 2?

Comment: Added a tentative answer below. Will look again later, there could be other problems. Maybe test turning off AllowSameVersionUpgrades as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***From Log***: ***`What product does this product code from the log file belong to?`***
>
> `Property(S): WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED = {8BC4D6BF-C0CF-48EB-A229-FC692208DFF0}`

***Product Code & Product Name***: Maybe try to run this script to figure out what product that really is: **`1)`** copy & paste the script below into notepad, **`2)`** save as ANSI file: **`"Product Code Lookup.vbs"`** on desktop, **`3)`** double click script file to run:

```vb
On Error Resume Next ' we ignore all errors
Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
search = Trim(InputBox("Please paste or type in the product code you want to look up details for:", _
              "Find Product Details (test GUID provided):", "{8BC4D6BF-C0CF-48EB-A229-FC692208DFF0}"))
If search = vbCancel Or Trim(search) = "" Then
   WScript.Quit(0)
End If

For Each product In installer.ProductsEx("", "", 7)
   If (product.ProductCode = search) Then
      MsgBox "Product Code: " & product.ProductCode & vbNewLine & _
             "Product Name: " & product.InstallProperty("ProductName") & vbNewLine & _
             "Product Version: " & product.InstallProperty("VersionString"), vbOKOnly, "Match Found:"
      Exit For
   End If
Next

MsgBox "Completed product scan.", vbOKOnly, "Scan Complete"
```

> ***Full List***: If you want a text file with all products listed, [please check the VBScript here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup/29937569#29937569) (towards bottom).

***AllowSameVersionUpgrades***: Just answered another major upgrade question. Maybe skim it too: **[WIX does not uninstall older version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989906/wix-does-not-uninstall-older-version/56991527#56991527)**. Remember that only the first 3 digits of the **`ProductVersion`** affect major upgrades. I am also not too keen on the **`"AllowSameVersionUpgrades"`** approach, I prefer the plain and simple major upgrade variant - like this (just my 2 cents, business requirements are always hard):

```
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
```

***Upgrade Table***: It would help to see the actual upgrade table. Is there anything funky in there? Multiple entries? Maybe you have re-used the same upgrade code for separate products? Upgrade code should remain the same for a product line or family of products that share upgrade handing. It should not be the same for different products that you want to upgrade separately. Generally speaking.

---

***Links***:

- [Determine msiexec exit code when msi file already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739347/determine-msiexec-exit-code-when-msi-file-already-installed/59674645#59674645)

Comment: Thank you!  Your script discovered an very old version of the program that was installed via the One Click Deployment with a version number on 1.0.5.1.  It is not a 'authorized' release.  I have updated and redeployed my installer with a new product code and a version of 1.1.1.1.  I will report back on the outcome.

Comment: With regard to the **AllowSameVersionUpgrades** flag-  That was a recent addition to the installer, a suggestion from another article.  The problem existed without it and its addition had no observable effect.

Comment: Great. Do skim [that linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56991527/129130) with the list of some of the common major upgrade problems.

Comment: Stein Asmul, thanks again. This was helpful.  It has solved the "Newer Version" issue.  The installation  is still still not working, but the symptoms are now different.  I am going to post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Is it deployed as an Application or Package in SCCM? If it is an application, what's the detection method? If it is using the same product code as the detection method, it may think that it has already been installed on the machine.

Best Regards,
Ray

Comment: Thanks for your questions Ray. I have added the answers above.